# Computer stuck on 1024x768 resolution after reboot

Tags: nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

I booted up my computer today to find that it is stuck at quite a low resolution. I'm using an nvidia Quadro M1000M graphics card and have tried all the non-server drivers in the additional drivers app. I only have knowledge of the terminal and commands regarding displays (i did try xrandr though), so most of the answers I found I couldn't use. This kind of just happened out of the blue, nothing leading up to it but perhaps an update. tried using nvidia's driver app thingy but I couldn't get the hang of it. I've wasted far too much time on this already please help. Using Ubuntu 22.04.2.

Comment: almost forgot, xrandr outputted:

Comment: xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1024 x 768, current 1024 x 768, maximum 1024 x 768
default connected primary 1024x768+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      76.00*